# Insert data in LINQ Database

Tags: c#, linq

I wonder why I can't insert data into database using LINQ. I created Serviced-Base database.

When I run the program, there is no error, but still no data appears in database table.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext ds = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    Customer cst = new Customer();

    cst.CustName = textBoxNama.Text;
    cst.Phone = int.Parse(textBoxHP.Text);
    cst.CustAddress = textBoxAlamat.Text;

    ds.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(cst);

    try
    {
        ds.SubmitChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {   
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? It will be helpful.

Comment: There is no error message. Program run successfully, but data that i've inserted couldnt appear

Comment: Put everything in a try-catch and let's see what's the exception.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek The exception isn't swallowed. This is more likely to be yet another localDb or AttachDbFileName confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are connected to the correct database(check connection string).